# `Network Manager` GUI Missing in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

If I go to `Settings > Network` I think I'm supposed to be able to select my Wifi Network manager by clicking the gear icon. Shown below to the right of *"1000 Mb/s On/Off"*.

[image]

But my Wireless connection doesn't show up at all on this GUI dialog shown above. I can only see the *VPN* box and the *Network Proxy* box. The *Wired* box is completely missing (in my case it's actually a wireless connection).

I need to get to the network manager, so I can access all the settings below.

[image]

Comment: Look over at "Wifi" in the left column.  Wifi gets put in its own management category now.  Alternatively, use `nm-connection-editor` - the old school original network manager connection editor that everyone using Ubuntu 16.04 (and not GNOME) will remember.

Comment: not in front of my Ubuntu box right now, but I think I tried that and there was no gear there or when I clicked on the gear it didn't bring me to Network manager. Of course I'll have to try later when I'm in front of the machine. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: the gear is actually lthe hamburger menu and then "Known Wifi Networks".  Alternatively, `nm-connection-editor` will list the wifi configs as well.

Comment: Maybe you've disabled the WiFi network, either by using some keyboard buttons or from the system menu (top right on the panel)?

Comment: I didn't know I had to use the hamburger menu. There's actually no gear there in the `Settings > Wifi`. Unfortunately there's lacking consistency between `Settings > Network` and `Settings > Wifi` at this point in time.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm totally agree, GNOME 3 Settings network managements features are the very entry-level ATM, comparing to original Network Manager GUI and Applet.*

## How to enable classic Network Manager GUI for Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

*(For current user.)*

Command-line solution:

```
# Make sure is's installed
sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome

# Enable application desktop item
sed 's/^NotShowIn=/#NotShowIn=/g' /usr/share/applications/nm-connection-editor.desktop > ~/.local/share/applications/nm-connection-editor.desktop

# Set applet to auto-start
sed 's/^NotShowIn=/#NotShowIn=/g; s/^NoDisplay=/#NoDisplay=/g' /usr/share/applications/nm-applet.desktop > ~/.config/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
```